# What is the nginx.conf ERROR: 'directive not allowed here'?

Tags: nginx

What is the NGinx 'directive not allowed here' error?   I am trying to use NGinx for the first time, and within a Docker container, and I am using example configurations from other websites that seem to be correct configurations, but I get this error, no matter how I configure the nginx.conf file, and I don't know why.

```
2018/03/10 20:52:20 [emerg] 1#1: "user" directive is not allowed 
  here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6

nginx: [emerg] "user" directive is not allowed here 
  in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
```

[Link to my Github project branch (not master) demonstrating the problem.](https://github.com/djangofan/docker-tomcat7-cluster/tree/broken1)

I have Googled this error and see lots of answers suggesting it is a simple fix and I have tried them all.

For example, if I configure my nginx.conf file like so, I get the error:

```
# nginx.conf
user  nobody;
```

Comment: I haven't used nginx or docker, but from the error message it looks like your file isn't the main `nginx.conf` (i.e. `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`), but some additional config file that gets loaded elsewhere (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/...`). What does the main config file contain?

Comment: Is https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/ what you're using? Because (under *Complex configuration*) that also says to install your config file as `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: @melpomene  Thank you , that fixed it.  My updated repo is here: https://github.com/djangofan/docker-tomcat7-cluster

Answer (score 5):

For anybody in my case (Docker + templates), the following might help.

I was getting this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
```

The problem is that the template, at least in this official NGINX Docker image, is not meant to be a full config.
It's included at the http block at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file in the image:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

(...)

http {
    (...)

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

In my case, the solution was removing everything but my own `http` config.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a reply by @melpomene, 3 things fixed it:

1. First, I had to copy my `nginx.conf` into the proper location according to 
     Nginx ['complex config'](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) documentation.
2. I had to also copy (via docker run volume mount) an empty `/etc/nginx/logs` 
     folder into place because it seems Nginx couldn't create the folder on its own?
3. I had to supply a `mime.types` file.

My updated repo is here:  https://github.com/djangofan/docker-tomcat7-cluster